# How to catch mouse left down if data template has a transparent background?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseevent, datatemplate

My `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
<StackPanel MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
```

However I can't catch mouse left button down. If I set the background of the template to some color, it is ok.

How do I create a transparent `DataTemplate` and catch the `MouseLefButtonDown` event?

Thank you.

Comment: Technically, your StackPanel is transparent, but you actually have Background set as null. This is different than setting the Background="Transparent", which will result in the same look but your StackPanel will receive mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to catch mouse events on the StackPanel itself you just have to set its background brush to be transparent:

```
<StackPanel MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        Background="Transparent" Height="400" Width="400" >
<Button Content="dfsdf"/>
```

Comment: Well this is my problem. If background is Transparetn, I can't receive event. If it is set to Black, White etc I can receive event MouseLeftButtonDown.

To better explain, I need to have list box item with transaprent background I'm able to drag by mouse. Therefore I need to receive MouseLeftButtonDown and start drag operation.

Answer (score 1):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` is a bubbling event. That means it fires first at the deepest possible level, then "bubbles" upward through the logical tree. If you have content contained in your `StackPanel` that is handling `MouseLeftButtonDown`, then you will never see the event bubble upward, and thus it will never reach your `StackPanel`.

`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, on the other hand, is a tunneling event. That means that it will fire first at the top-level container, and then "tunnel" downwards through the logical tree until it reaches the lowest level. Try changing your event to:

```
<StackPanel PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

And see if you can catch it then.