# C#/WPF: Event hander triggered only when over child element

Tags: c#, wpf

I have attached Event Handlers to a Border but it seems they only work when i drag over a child `TextBlock`

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="20" Margin="15" BorderBrush="Black" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Border_DragEnter" Drop="Border_Drop">
    <TextBlock Text="Drop images here" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
</Border>
```

Comment: If you add Padding="10" to your border and then drag over the padding area that appears around the text box, do your event handlers get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a

```
Background="Transparent"
```

to your Border for it to receive mouse events.

Read more: [How to catch mouse left down if data template has a transparent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325008/how-to-catch-mouse-left-down-if-data-template-has-a-transparent-background)